# How to find uuid of iphone through phonegap?

Tags: php, iphone, cordova

I want to check whether the user has already voted for a particular page,this is done by checking the existence of device uuid in database,so can anybody help me out to find the device uuid from phonegap and use that device uuid to check in ma php script???

Answer (score 4):

i would avoid using the UUID, apple will probably reject your application if you do use it. use alternative methods to identify a single user instead.

```
TechCrunch reports that Apple has begun rejecting iOS apps for the use of a 
unique device identifier known as the UDID. The site notes that several developers 
have reported rejections for the use of the UDID in the past week, and Apple is said 
to be ramping up the enforcement of this policy over the next few weeks.
```

source: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1348294

Comment: so we are not supposed to use device uuid in are app??or is there any other way to use it?

Comment: you should definitly look for another way to identify your user.

Answer (score 2):

Its important to note the difference between a UDID and a UUID.

UDID "unique device id" is hardware specific. It never changes for a particular device. For this reason, it has become a privacy concern and Apple is blocking apps that try to use this. As a result, Apple has generated an opt-out-able "device id" hash, particularly for advertisement usage. This new ID hash is called IFA and is available in iOS 6.0+. This is a fair alternative, but can be disabled by the user at anytime.

UUID "universally unique id" is not hardware specific. It is a hash used to identify a device; but not particularly an absolute value. PhoneGap generates a UUID based on device properties; this is what you get when you do device.uuid. If you delete the app and reinstall, you will get a new id hash. *UUID is not being blocked by Apple*.

Answer (score 0):

Check Phonegap Documentation.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html#Device

```
function onDeviceReady() {
        var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');

        element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' + 
                            'Device PhoneGap: ' + device.phonegap + '<br />' + 
                            'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' + 
                            'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' + 
                            'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
    }
```

Comment: can u pls tell me where should i use this code?i mean is it in js file or html ?

Comment: Be aware that the UDID is deprecated and apple is starting to reject apps still using it.

Comment: you just checkout the stuff in phonegap developer forum and all these people saying about rejecting the apps which i m not aware. so kindly check for that feasibility also.